# Refactoring function in c

Tags: c, function, refactoring

I have a piece of code that look like this :

```
void printdatamatrix(int xp, int yp, int h)
{
   int wide;
   int x = xp;
   int y = yp;

   if(h>=40)
   {
      wide = h /9;
   }
   else
   { 
      wide = h / 4;
   }

   /*vertical - L-shape*/
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   x += wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   x += wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   x += wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   x += wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   x += wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   x += wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);

   /*horizontal - L-shape*/
   x = xp;
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);

   x = xp;
   y = yp;
   x += wide;
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);

   x = xp;
   y = yp;
   x += wide * 2;
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide * 2;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide * 2;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);

   x = xp;
   y = yp;
   x += wide * 3;
   y -= wide * 3;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide * 2;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
   y -= wide * 4;
   drawsquare(x, y, wide);
         .
         .
         .
        etc
```

The drawsquare(x,y,wide) function creates a square in order to form a datamatrix (barcode).
  I would like to know if I could refactor the printdatamatrix(int xp, int yp, int h) function to be 
  smaller. The only thing I have thought is to write 2 for loops and include the L-Shape (one for 
  vertical and another one for horizontal).

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about some loops? Like `for (unsigned i = 0; i < 7; ++i, x += wide) { drawsquare(x, y, wide); }`? Start like that, and then see if it can be generalized further (for example much code seems very similar, and could perhaps be refactored into separate functions).

Comment: By the way, if the code *works* (an important requirement) then this seems to be more fitted on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is what I was thinking about the first part (vertical-horizontal), but what should I do if the y or the x is incremented by 2, then by 3, then by 1  etc.? I have to initialise the x and and the y in order to create the next lines of squares. thank you

Comment: Use an array for those steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a nested loop to draw my pattern stored in a 2d array. It is like this:

```
void printdatamatrix(int xp, int yp, int h, int dirn)
{
    int wide = _convertPixelsToMmForDataMatrix(h); 
    int x = xp; 
    int y = yp; 
    unsigned int i, j;

    static bool my_data[ROWS][COLS] = {
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0 },
    { 1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1 },
    { 1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0 },
    { 1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1 },
    { 1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1 },
    { 1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1 },
    { 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0 }
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 12; ++j)
        {
            if (my_data[i][j])
            { 
                switch (dirn)
                {
                    case 1: // 270
                        drawsquare(x + j * wide, y + i * wide, wide);
                        break;
                    case 2: // 0
                        drawsquare(x + i * wide, y - j * wide, wide);
                        break;
                    case 3: // 90
                        drawsquare(x - j * wide, y - i * wide, wide);
                        break;
                    case 4: // 180
                        drawsquare(x - i * wide, y + j * wide, wide);
                        break;
                }
            }
       }
   }
}
```